# Having issues in transforming my data for further analysis In R

Tags: r, dataframe, linear-regression, data-transform

I have a dataset here:

'''[dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cF_iel1PC6BxWv828BofZ1SXvRd-linn/view?usp=sharing)

I want to perform linear and multiple  regression.`MoralRelationship` and `SkeletalP` are both dependent variables while others are independent. I tried all the various method of Transformation I know but it did not yield any meaningful result from my `diagnostic` plot

I did this:

```
lm1<- lm(MoralRelationship ~ RThumb + RTindex + RTmid + RTFourth + RTFifth + Lthumb + Lindex
+ LTMid + LTFourth + LTfifth + BldGRP1 + BlDGR2, data=data)
```

I did same for `SkeletalP`

I did a`diagnostic plot` for both. then Tried to `normalize` the variables because there is correlation nor linearity. I took `square term`, `log` ,`Sqrt`of all `independent`  variables also,`log`,`1/x` but no better output.
I also did

```
`lm(SkeletalP ~ RThumb + I(RThumb^2), data=data)`
```

if i will get a better result with one variable.

The independent variables are right skewed except for `ANB` which is normally distributed.

is there method I can use to transform my data? most importantly, to be uniformly distributed so that i can perform other statistical test.

Answer (score 0):

Your dataset is kind of small. You can try dimensionality reduction like PCA, but I don't think it's appropriate here. It's also harder to interpret.

Have you tried other models? Tuning might help the fit of your regression models (e.g. Lasso/Ridge L1/L2 regulation)

Comment: I will try other Models as suggested